# How do I troubleshoot my electric oven?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, oven

I've got a Kenmore electric oven, model no. 911.94391790. The other day, the oven was on bake mode @ 350° I heard it make some funny beeping noises and the clock/display area started to flash random digits and lines, then the unit shut off.

After a few minutes, I turned it back on and about 5 minutes later, the same thing happened  as described above.

Now, the clock/display area doesn't work at all. **The oven doesn't work in bake, broil or clean mode. However, the burners still work properly.**

I'm unsure what to test to determine the problem. If I had to guess I would think it would be the main board, since the display doesn't work, but again I'm unsure.

Is there anything I can test or rule out? If I have to replace the mainboard, what steps need to be taken?

Answer (score 1):

I reset the breaker, unplugged and plugged the oven back in, and it started working again.

Comment: It could be a poor plug connection, especially on the neutral pin (the control logic is likely working from the 120 volts obtained from the neutral pin). Replugging could have cleared off some corrosion from a pin and let current flow better again. This might happen again in a few months or years. Next time, do some extra cleaning of the plug pins.