# Electric stove oven stopped working

Tags: electrical

We used our electric stove to heat up our home. We turned all 4 top burners on and the oven. We left the oven door open. It stayed on about 45 minutes. Well, i turned everything off for about 2 minutes. When i went back to cook, the digital clock and oven went out. Top burners still work. What happened?

Comment: What make and model oven is this?

Comment: Does it have a thermostatically controlled fan which cools the electronics? If so, was it coming on when you were using it as a space heater?

Comment: Anytime there's a power supply problem with an oven, the chassis of the oven MIGHT now be energized with 120 volts. In that case, touching the oven and also anything that's grounded (like your sink) would electrocute you.  Did you smell any funny electrical or burning smells?

Answer (score 2):

> We used our electric stove to heat up our home.

Uh, like voiding warranties do you?

> What happened?

Sounds like you busted it.  Ovens are NOT space heaters.....

If you're lucky, there's a thermal fuse that will self-reset in an hour or so of no use.  You might try cycling the breaker.  But really don't.  If its acting badly because of a wiring problem the last thing you want to do is re-energize that wiring.

If the oven does not start working after several hours of non-use (thermal fuse), you have destroyed it.  You get to buy a new oven now.  If the new oven does not work, then you also get to run new wiring from the breaker panel to the oven.

It's going to be very expensive.  But cheaper than paying to rebuild the structure and put up room and board in a burn ward for all the residents.

[image]

Comment: Running all burners and the oven at once is also a rare occurrence, which tests the limits of the wiring.   It can reveal problems that may have existed for awhile, but were never stressed to the breaking point.

Comment: If household heat is also electric, then what I just said also applies to the main electric service for the home.  I assume you are maxing out everything capable of making heat, along with the hot water cycling on and off in the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

The oven went out on our 24-year-old GE electric range and it turned out it was the 'timer' assembly which is also a controller. I first tried to get a new timer but none was available. There is a company in Ontario, Canada which sells reconditioned ones, but they were out of stock of the model I needed. I removed the mine, sent it to them, they repaired it and sent it back (~$US 100.00). Turnaround was about a week. That was 5 years ago.

http://www.appliancetimers.com/

There are maybe 6 connections between the stove and the 'timer' and when I first put it in and connected it, it didn't work. I pulled off each connector and slid it back on and then it worked!

I don't really remember how I diagnosed the problem as the timer. I first was convinced it was probably the thermistor temp sensor but it's resistance checked out. I had the full specs because I had installed it. You may be able to get info on line with the make, model no. and serial no.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the circuit breaker and letting it sit for 10 min and try operating it. Did you have the oven on bake or on broil when using it as a space heater?

Comment: If the cord plugs in, then unplug it and re-plug it in. See this http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29417/how-do-i-troubleshoot-my-electric-oven?rq=1.